# No Jupiter char (U+2643) on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, unicode

Recently i was reading this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols) on a windows xp pc. i recognised that there was no Jupiter unicode character (this one: `♃`), in fact there was only a whitespace. i was suprised, because when i googled this symbol i found [this](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=jupiter), which shows the sign correctly. then i tried to change the font in the firefox inspector to Arial, Verdana, Times but with none of them it worked. coping it from the site and pasting it to openoffice gave me also only a whitespace.

So i would ask you if this char is not available in the fonts of windows xp or can i add it somehow?

Comment: [This link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2643/fontsupport.htm) gives a list of fonts which support the character: you will need to investigate which ones you can install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JUPITER character is included in a few fonts only. The [Fileformat.info page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2643/fontsupport.htm) mentioned by @AFH in a comment lists the most important of them, but it is also contained in ALPHA-Demo, Meiryo, Meiryo UI, MS Gothic and a few other MS fonts, Sun-ExtA. XITS, and XITS Math.

None of those fonts is available in Windows XP by default. If you have Microsoft Office installed, it may have come with a version of Arial Unicode MS font that has the charater. But there are different versions of Arial Unicode MS around.

It is difficult to analyze how the [Unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=jupiter) site handles the issue, but it seems that at least one of its strategies is to use a downloadable font (web font) via `@font-face`. This means that some font is downloaded and used by the browser, but not installed in your system, so it cannot be used by other programs.

To make the character available (in different programs) in your system, simply download and install a suitable free font, or fonts. For example, DejaVu Sans (a sans-serif font) and Linux Libertine (a serif font); note that DejaVu Serif has a sans-serif glyph for this character.